# area gets clipped when status bar is hidden

Tags: iphone

I have a requirement to show a viewcontroller in full screen(modal segue). I am simply hiding the status bar on top. I am calling this code on viewdidload of viewcontroller.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

Now one issue arises is that on very bottom of screen, area gets clipped or like cut of exactly size of status bar. How could i fix this ?

Note: I want to hide status for only one view controller in my app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above said answers are right.... But thing to know is status bar reservers 20px in height and 460 px is meant for view in a viewcontroller.

Have a check on it. Just goto one of viewcontrollers.

Click on **controller view** its **frame** will be  **(0,0,320,460)**. Where **(0,0,320, 20) is meant for status bar**.  And notice that view size **isnt adjustable** in terms of **height**. Here if we hide satus bar. then view entity's position changes that actual intended position as view will pulled by some factor.

Click on tab were u can see its property. Set Status bar to None.  Now size of view is **adjustable** in all terms **(i.e., origin, width, height)**. Now change view frame to **(0,0,320,480)**

Comment: the status bar can be either 20 or 40 pixels high, don't assume it is always 20.  It's 40 while in a call or when personal hotspot is on.  And now with iPhone5 the frame can be 480 or 568 high.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to hide the status bar (and this will work on any version) is to go into you Info.plist, right click to add a row and select Status Bar Initially hidden.

or

```
[application setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

It is worked for me.
I was also facing the same problem.

Comment: I want only one particular viewcontroller to have hidden status. Doing it from Info.plist wont effect all view controllers ??

Comment: ok if you want to do it for one viewcontroller then go for or (second )option ,[application setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hide your Status bar initially in PList. In xib, CLick on view then on inspector change your status bar to **none**.